# Array pointer and pointer array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

What is the difference between an array pointer and a pointer array in C?

Comment: This is probably of use to you Ksindev.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c

Comment: Without a code example your question is a little ambiguous. Are you asking about the difference between "a pointer to an array" and "an array of pointers"?

Comment: If you figure out what each of those are, the difference will follow.

Comment: It's like the difference between five people in one car and one person in five cars. (One is distinctly more common than the other.)

Comment: @KerrekSB Especially if it's the same person. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **array pointer** is a pointer referring to an array.
You could access items using pointer arithmetic, and in the opposite direction you could use pointer to access items in an array manner.

```
 int array [20];
 int a = *(array + 10);
 int b = array[10];

 int *p;
 p = array;

 int c = *(p + 10);
 int d = p[10];
```

all approaches will work, a,b,c,d will get to same value. However, use the different approaches with care.
The difference between array and p is

```
 p ++; // allowed
 array ++; // fail
```

An array of pointer just mean your array items are pointers (to what type however).

```
 char* parray[20];
```

This array holds 20 pointers to "char" or depending of interpretation to "strings"

So parray is the **array pointer** of an **array of char pointers**

Answer (score 2):

Array pointer points to array, and pointer array is array of pointer, that may point to somewhere.

```
int array[10]; // `array` is an array pointer

int* pointers_array[10];
```

Comment: `array` isn't an array pointer, it's the name of an array. If you do `&array` you get a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a pointer.